# yodlee httpError on service integration

Tags: web-services, jar, yodlee

I am trying to use the rest api as per the instructions mentioned in the site.
I have registered on the developed portal and go my CoBrand and User details.
I am trying to invoke the rest api and i am getting the following exception

*org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [Jersey Web Application] in context with path [/fundomentor] threw exception [org.glassfish.jersey.server.ContainerException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/httpclient/HttpMethod] with root cause
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethod*

I have added the follwing jars to my buildpath 
commons-codec-1.4.jar
commons-httpclient-3.1.jar
commons-logging-1.1.1.jar
httpclient-4.2.5.jar
httpcore-4.2.4.jar
java-json.jar
javax-ssl-1_1.jar
JRE System Library[1.7]
I also tried by adding 
apache-httpcomponents-httpclient.jar
commons-httpclient-3.1-source.jar
But no luck.i also replaced my source with the rest api sample present in the Yodlee site and  i try invoking it using POSTMAN (Google Chrome addon); even then the same http error occurs.

Can some one help with the jars to be used and versions.

Answer (score 0):

The following jar files worked for me-

> commons-codec-1.4.jar
>
> commons-httpclient-3.1.jar
>
> commons-logging-1.1.1.jar
>
> httpclient-4.2.5.jar
>
> httpcore-4.2.4.jar
>
> java-json.jar

Make sure to copy jar files into WEB-INF/lib folder. Hope this solves your issue.

Regards,

Krithik

Comment: Sorry Krithik.. There was no Luck.

Comment: It seems that it is unable to find the servlet. Please do the following checks - * see if the servlet is configured properly in the web.xml.
*Ensure to keep the jar files in WEB-INF/lib path 
*If you are trying to call servlet using jar then that jar must be in the web.xml as a resource .

Later restart the server.